# Scraping urls from google including a date range

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

Would it be possible to get the results in a time range (e.g. from 02-02-2018 to 02-03-2018) from google search, avoiding the HTTPSConnectionPool error?

I am currently using the following code

```
urls=[]
count=0

q='Brexit'

for url in search(q):
        r = requests.get(url, timeout=None)
        r.status_code
        count=count+1
        urls.append(url)
```

to scrape urls, preferably in a specified time window. However, I cannot do this as I am getting the following error:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.___.org', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /Brexit/ (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60]
>   Operation timed out'))

and I do not know if I can fix it and/or how to fix it.
Could you please tell me if there is a way to avoid the following error message and get the results in a specified date range? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you add more of the code? Is search using the google api or is it your custom function?

Comment: This is the code that I am currently using. I can just add the libraries that I am considering but at the moment this returns me (or at least it should return) the urls from google. I am not using Google API as I think there is a limit of 100 results that you can get (I am not sure about that). The problems regarding this code are two: the first is the error that stops the code; the second one is the date range that is not implemented as I do not know how to do that.

Comment: What is the `search` function/which library is it using?

Comment: I am only using `import requests` to get the urls

Comment: so for google specific, you can have the date filter in the query itself. so `requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=brexit+before%3A02-03-2018+after%3A02-02-2018', timeout=None)`

Comment: Let me know if you have more questions or how to write this?

Comment: Thank you so much, grahum. I would need to include in a more general query, like start_date=' ... ' and end_date=' ... ', but I think it is doable. Do you know how to avoid that error message too? If you could add your comment and this other information (if you know it) as answer, I will mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalize the query using the dates. 
So for google specifically, you can have range operators for specific dates.

If your `search` function is just `request.get('https://google.com/search?q={}'.format(q))` you can make use of the following code:

```
urls=[]
count=0

q='Brexit before:02-03-2018 after:02-02-2018'

for url in search(q):
        r = requests.get(url, timeout=None)
        r.status_code
        count=count+1
        urls.append(url)
```

This will solve the dates issue. For the error, I think you are trying to get a url where the `href` is '___'. That maybe just a bad link, so I would add just a try except block and log it. Thus I would consider filtering more (using `BeautifulSoup` to get just the results. 
So the code would be:

```
import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

q='Brexit before:02-03-2018 after:02-02-2018'
req = request.get('https://google.com/search?q={}'.format(q), timeout=None)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
hrefs = soup.find_all('a') # this is all the hrefs. 
for href in hrefs: 
     try: 
         r = requests.get(url)
     except Exception as e: 
         print(e)
```